# GitHub 'Nothing Added to Commit' and ipynb_checkpoints untracked

Tags: python-3.x, git, github, jupyter-notebook

I deleted a few cells in my Jupyter Notebook and when I tried to commit to GitHub I got a

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
.ipynb_checkpoints/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Not sure what happened. Even if I add a bunch of stuff still says everything is up to date. For reference I am just running...

```
git add *
git commit -m " [message ] "
git push origin master
```

Git log shows i'm on master. I'm pretty new to Jupyter notebooks

Comment: Also, I just saw this in the top right of my notebook when I tried to manually save "_xsrf argument missing from POST"

Comment: So I wouldn't call this "solving the problem" so I am posting this in the comments... I shutdown the notebook (I'm running it through Anaconda). Restarted it (lost all of my changes) remade the changes and it worked without an issue.. So I assume it has something to do with the "_xsrf". That said I would love to know what actually happened. Also if I just try to delete a cell and then git commit it throws the same issue. I have to add code for git commit to work